# jquery ui datepicker don't trigger onClose when clicked on btn

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use Jquery UI datepicker and I would like to prevent it from triggering `onClose` callback whenever clicked on button.

html:

```
<input type="text" id="picker" />
<a href="#" id="clear">Clear</a>
```

js:

```
$('#picker').datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
        console.log('closed');
    }
});
$('#clear').click(function(e) {
    console.log('do something else');
});
```

Problem is that when I open the picker and click on clear button then `onClose` callback is called. There is also no possibility to pass actual event to `onClose`, because it takes only currentDate and picker instance as arguments.

Is there way to trigger only click event and close the picker when user clicks on `#clear`-button?

I can't currently share jsfiddle, bacause page is down..

Answer (score 0):

The following should close datepicker on click of "clear" button :

```
$('#picker').datepicker({
    onClose: function() {
        console.log('closed');
        return false;
    }
});
$('#clear').click(function(e) {
    console.log('do something else');
    $( "#picker" ).datepicker("hide");
});
```

Cheers

Comment: yes, but `onClose` callback is called anyway if datepicker is open. My question was how to prevent it.

Comment: Have you checked the inline one in ui datepicker?

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#inline